# Access static object from other instance

Tags: c#, static, instance

I have a `Program class` which has:

```
private static ClientBase objClientBase = new ClientBase(new List<RecordType> { RecordType.none }, ModuleType.Monitor);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        objClientBase.Connect(); //IRRELEVANT
        objQueueMon = new Main(); //<-INSIDE THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ACCESS objClientBase
        objClientBase.MainModuleThreadManualResetEvent.WaitOne(); //IRRELEVANT
    }
```

This Progam creates a `Main class` instance as you see:

```
objQueueMon = new Main();
```

Notice that they are separated in different files, but the Main class instance is created inside the Program class.

Inside my Program class I want to access that `objClientBase`.

Do I have to create a constructor method and pass it or make a public access to it?
So what I want to achieve is, inside the Main class, do a `objClientBase.FUNCTION`

Comment: Please show a little more code, it is hard to deduce anything from two lines.

Comment: I added some but should not need more

Comment: Both of your suggested solutions would work, if you are asking which is better it's pretty subjective and difficult to determine given the small amount of code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exactly what you just said:

```
public class Main {

    private ClientBase _caller;

    public Main (ClientBase caller) {
        _caller = caller;
    }

}
```

Or, you can set it later

```
public class Main {

    private ClientBase _caller;

    public Main () {

    }

    // only your assembly sets it
    internal SetClientBase(ClientBase cb) {

        _caller = cb;
    }

    // but anyone gets it
    // Now you can let some client execute "Function"
    public ClientBase Caller {
        {return _caller;} 
    }

}
```

Just an example

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of your `Main` class to accept a `ClientBase` object, like this:

```
public class Main
{
    private ClientBase _clientBase;

    public Main(ClientBase clientBase)
    {
        _clientBase = clientBase;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Use ClientBase.FUNCTION here
        _clientBase.FUNCTION();
    }
}
```